# express-validator isStrongPassword() function is not working

Tags: express, express-validator

I'm trying to do validation test by using express-validator.

so far everything is working good except isStrongPassword()

```js
import {check} from "express-validator"


const val =   
    check('pwd')
        .exists()
        .withMessage('please enter the password')
        .isStrongPassword({minLength: 6})
        .withMessage('password is must be above six letters')

Router.post('/signup',val,SignUp)


const SignUp = async(req,res) => {
    // if email and password are invalid  throw the errors
    const errors = validationResult(req).array();
    if (errors && errors.length) {
    console.log(errors);
    res.status(400).json({ errors });
```

my code is like that .but when I request password 1 letter or 7 letters regardless  It just call error. It seems to be doesn`t work
anybody who knows why it happened? Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 4):

`isStrongPassword` has default values

[image]

Either you override the other properties with 0 or just follow the default values.

IMHO, a strong password should respect the combination of lower case, upper case, number, and special character, not only the minimal length.

I hope this answers your problem.

Comment: Thank you for comment  but  I tryed it again by default. This one is just not working can`t validate any sentence. so I just let it down temporaily

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
const val =   
    check('pwd','the password must contain 6 characters, 1 lower case letter, 1 upper case letter, 1 number and 1 symbol')
        .isStrongPassword({minLength: 6})
```

if the password is wrong you can see this in the response somethig like:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "type": "field",
            "value": "sn5w@E",
            "msg": "the password must contain 6 characters, 1 lower case letter, 1 upper case letter, 1 number and 1 symbol",
            "path": "pwd",
            "location": "body"
        }
    ]
}
```